# No se renderiza el componente Outlet

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, redux

buen dia, estoy tratando de proteger las rutas de mi front-end, hago la validacion mediante el estado global del usuario que se manda a pedir en el login, pero al momento de renderizarlo solamente me muestra una pagina en blanco

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Redirect from "../Redirect/redirect";

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const userData = useSelector((state) => state.userData);

  switch (userData) {
    case null:
      return (
        <>
          <h1>Cargando</h1>
        </>
      );
    case "invalidUser":
      return (
        <>
          <h1>Credenciales invalidas</h1>
          <Redirect />
        </>
      );
    case true:
      return <Outlet />;
  }
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

Cuando intento logear un con usuario invalido si entra en el componente necesario o de que otra forma podria implementarlo teniendo en cuenta que desde el login pide la informacion del usuario dependiendo de si esta en la base de datos o no?

Las rutas de verian de la siguiente forma:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
          <Route exact path="/home" element={<HomeStudent />} />
          <Route exact path="/Cursos" element={<Classroom />} />
          <Route exact path="/Materias" element={<Classroom />} />
          <Route exact path="/alumnos" element={<Alumnos />} />
          <Route exact path="/Aulas/materia/:id" element={<Detail />} />
          <Route exact path="/formAlumno" element={<Form />} />
          <Route exact path="/formProfesor" element={<FormProfesor />} />
          <Route exact path="/formsubject" element={<FormSubject />} />
          <Route exact path="/carrito" element={<Carrito />} />
          <Route exact path="/Stripe" element={<AppStripe />} />
        </Route>

        <Route exact path="/" element={<Landing />} />
        <Route exact path="/sobreNosotros" element={<Caracteristicas />} />
        <Route exact path="/contacto" element={<Contacto />} />
        <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```